# evaluate number of poles lying on the right,left side of s-plane and on the jw-axis?

Tags: control-system

the transfer function is \$\   T(s)= \dfrac {1} {2s^5+3s^4+2s^3+3s^2+2s+1} \$
I solved it using RH criterion by evaluating the columns but results are different when i solved it with by matlab they are different.

Comment: Is the denominator all the terms from 2s^5 to 1? Also you should show what you have attempted.

Comment: i had attempted it and i got a two times sign change in the first row of the routh column which means there are two poles on the right half of the s-plane . and the solution i found using matlab are 
  -1.3307,0.3284 + 0.8899i,0.3284 - 0.8899i,-0.4131 + 0.4969i,-0.4131 - 0.4969i

Comment: If you got different answers with these two methods, then you made a mistake.

Comment: can anyone help me

Comment: Nobody can point out your mistake if you don't show us your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Maybe your MatLab script is wrong</del>. I try with Octave

```
    GNU Octave, version 3.8.1
Copyright (C) 2014 John W. Eaton and others.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".

Additional information about Octave is available at http://www.octave.org.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit http://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read http://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.
For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.

>>roots([0.5 3 2 3 2 1])

ans =

  -5.44527 + 0.00000i
   0.17829 + 0.92802i
   0.17829 - 0.92802i
  -0.45565 + 0.45131i
  -0.45565 - 0.45131i

>>
```

and it shows two right-half plane roots.

Your MatLab output shows two right-half plane roots, but different values.

**Revision**

With a new lecture of your question, I note that the coefficient of \$s^ 5\$ is not 0.5. The transfer function is

\$
T(s)=\dfrac{1}{2s^5+3s^4+2s^3+3s^2+2s+1}
\$

and using Octave to find the roots of denominator

```
>> roots([2 3 2 3 2 1])
ans =

  -1.33069 + 0.00000i
   0.32844 + 0.88991i
   0.32844 - 0.88991i
  -0.41309 + 0.49692i
  -0.41309 - 0.49692i

>>
```

that is the same result as your MatLab execution.

The transfer function has 5 poles, 1 real and 4 complex. Two complex poles has positive real part, that is, two poles are on the right-half plane.

Comment: This might not be the transfer function OP meant - I think it might be 1 / (2s^5 + 3s^4 + ...)

Comment: Anyway, with the RH method, the location of the roots of any polynomial in the plane is evaluated. If these roots represent poles or zeros of a transfer function, it is another analysis.
As described in the question, the application of RH gave the correct result, and also the execution of MatLab, although not consistent with the values I got.

Comment: i am unable to get where the location of roots are ,the way i calculated using RH criterion gives me 2 root on the right half of s plane

Comment: @Cielo OK. A complex number, has a real part and imaginary part. The _s_ variable is a complex number and can be represented in a complex plane, with real values on the abscises and imaginary values on the ordinates. The poles 0.32844 + 0.88991 i and 0.32844 - 0.88991 i has a positive real part, then, the points that represent this poles on the complex plane _s_ , resides on the right-half.

Comment: how can evaluate the number of imaginary roots

Comment: in RH criterion there is root on imaginary axis if one row has all its zero elements